# Get the value of all checked checkboxes and insert these to the database - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wanted to get all the values of the checked checkboxes and insert all of these to the database.

```
<form action="test.php" id="poll" name="poll" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" class='lol' name="lol[]" value="cake">Cake :D
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class='lol' name="lol[]" value="pie">Pie
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class='lol' name="lol[]" value="cupcakes">Cupcakes ^O^
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" class='lol' name="lol[]" value="brownies">Brownies :D
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

This is my php code.

```
$checkBox = $_POST['lol'];

for ($i=0; $i< sizeof($checkBox); $i++) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO castvote (candidate) VALUES ('".$checkBox[$i]."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: instead of doing multiple INSERT, do once like that: `INSERT INTO castvode (candidate) VALUES ("yourvalue"), ("yourvalues2")`

Comment: What is the problem? Is the query executed? Is the POST data correctly retrieved?...

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: the query has executed but the candidates has no values but the ID has updated. . .sorry, i dont know what the terms to use, i'm just a noob, and i just started college, hehehe

Comment: @RalphVillasoto avoid multiple insert, check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['lol'])){
  if (is_array($_POST['lol'])) {
    foreach($_POST['lol'] as $value){
      query here
    }
  } else {
      echo "nothing checked";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: mysql_query("INSERT INTO castvote (candidate) VALUES ('".$value."')") or die(mysql_error());

Answer (score 2):

your php code should like this,

```
<?php

$data     = "";
$checkBox = $_POST['lol']; 

foreach($_POST['lol'] as $value) {
    $data .= "(\"".$value."\"),"; // concatenate your checked values
}

$data = substr($data,0,strlen($data)-1); // for removing the `,` symbol
$query = "INSERT INTO castvote (candidate) VALUES ". $data. ";";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

> "use INSERT
>   statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several rows at a
>   time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some cases)
>   than using separate single-row INSERT statements." [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html)

Comment: Since there are **at most** 4 values to insert, this is a useless optimization. Unless there is evidence that there are performance issues with the MySQL server.

Comment: @Jocelyn please read the manual : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html

"use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some cases) than using separate single-row INSERT statements."

Comment: As I already wrote, with only 4 records to insert, it will not be considerably faster. There will be almost no performance gain. I use this kind of multi-inserts for a form that inserts 50000 records each time it is submitted. In this case, inserting records one at a time took 30 seconds, while inserting all records with one query took 0.3 second.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query looks like this: `INSERT INTO castvote (candidate) VALUES ("value","value2");` I mean you have to insert the *comma (,)* between the values. I would also use different names in the checkboxes.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
$array = array("foo", "bar", "hallo", "world"); //your array will be different
$text = "(";
for($i = 0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{
    if($i == count($array)-1)
    {
        $text .= '"'.$array[$i].'"';
    }
    else
    {
        $text .= '"'.$array[$i].'", ';
    }
}
$text .= ");";

$query = "INSERT INTO castvote (candidate) VALUES ".$text;
echo $query;
?>
```

Comment: i really don't know how to get ("value","value2")

Comment: I just updated my post, with this code you can create your query.

Answer (score 1):

use foreach loop and try creating a single query like this

```
INSERT INTO tablename(
`id` ,
`provider_id` ,
`service_id` ,
`voucher_id`
)
// your loop goes here
VALUES (
NULL , '78', '90', '94'
), (
NULL , '67', '78', '89'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code:

```
for ($j=0; $j < count($_POST['lol']);$j++) 
{
    $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO castvote (candidate) VALUES '".$_POST['lol'][$j]."')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add name attribute in your submit type input field then write your PHP code. Like -

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Vote">

<?php
if (isset($_POST["save"])) {
  $checkBox = $_POST['lol'];
  foreach ($checkBox as $key => $value) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO castvote (candidate) VALUES ('".$value."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  }
}
?>
```